# MVC External Login - Using Google People API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, google-people-api

I have a C# MVC project. I am attempting to aid the user registration process by retrieving user information from Google. I would like to access firstname, lastname, email and mobile number. All are required fields. I believe I need to use the Google People API. The Google+ API has been working fine but doesn't have mobile number. I am unsure on how to obtain this data. Currently in startup.auth I have:

```
        var googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleClientId"],
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleClientSecret"],
            Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = context =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:google:accesstoken", context.AccessToken, ClaimValueTypes.String, "Google"));
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, context.Email));
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Uri, context.User["image"]["url"].ToString()));
                    return Task.FromResult(true);
                }
            }
        };
        googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read");
        googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
        googleOptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
```

And in my Controller I have:

```
        if (loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider == "Google")
        {
            if (loginInfo.Email == null)
                loginInfo.Email = GetSchemasClaimValue(loginInfo, "emailaddress");
            firstName = GetSchemasClaimValue(loginInfo, "givenname");
            lastName = GetSchemasClaimValue(loginInfo, "surname");
            mobilePhone = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.MobilePhone);


            //proPic = GetSchemasClaimValue(loginInfo, "uri");
        }
```

All the information besides mobile phone is accessible and working as desired. I am just unsure of how to retrieve this data. I was hoping it would appear as a Claim in loginInfo but no claim exists for this case. The user is prompted to give the app permission to access mobile phone so I'm a little confused as to why there is no claim. Does a claim needs to be added in my startup.auth? How would that work? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar feature, i.e. getting data from Google People API, in [my sample Xamarin project](https://github.com/goh-chunlin/Burger) with backend hosted on Azure Mobile Apps (aka App Services). I did it as following.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse("Bearer " + accessToken);

    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me"))
    {
        var googlePlusUserInfo = 
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GooglePlusUserInfo>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        googlePlusUserInfo.Email = googlePlusUserInfo.Emails.Count() > 0 ? 

        googlePlusUserInfo.Emails.First().EmailAddress : "";

        googlePlusUserInfo.ProfilePicure.ImageUrl = 
        googlePlusUserInfo.ProfilePicure.ImageUrl.Split(new char[] { '?' })[0];

        return googlePlusUserInfo;
    }
}
```

[Complete code on Github](https://github.com/goh-chunlin/Burger/blob/master/burgerappService/Controllers/UserInfoController.cs).

If phone number is needed to be retrieved, then we can get it using:

```
googlePlusUserInfo.PhoneNumbers.CanonicalForm
```

Of course, [the model GooglePlusUserInfo](https://github.com/goh-chunlin/Burger/blob/master/SocialNetworkManagement/GooglePlus/GooglePlusUserInfo.cs) needs to be updated as well in order to match the JSON structure returned first. The JSON of the Google user profile with phone number returned is

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/...",
  "etag": "...",
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "CONTACT",
          "id": "1"
        }
      },
      "value": "88880000",
      "canonicalForm": "+65888800000",
      "type": "mobile",
      "formattedType": "Mobile"
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope this helps and please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hi, I've attempted this approach, however my JSon result looks like: 
{{
  "kind": "plus#person",
  "etag": "\"Sh4n9u6xxxNdphy12JkxmY\"",
  "emails": [
    {
      "value": "nic.che@xxx.co.za",
      "type": "account"
    }
  ],
  "objectType": "person",
  "id": "114157772521111131101",
  "displayName": "Nic Che",
  "name": {
    "familyName": "Che",
    "givenName": "Nic"
  },
  "image": {
    "url": "https://xxx=50",
    "isDefault": false
  },
  "isPlusUser": false,
  "language": "en",
  "verified": false,
  "domain": "xxx"
}}

I cannot find phoneNumbers

Comment: This answer is getting data from the [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people), which is different than the [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/).

Comment: @NicolasChetty Please refer to https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get. It seems like you need to specify "phoneNumbers" in `personFields`, the field mask to restrict which fields on the person are returned.

Answer (score 0):

The `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read` scope only works with the [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/). You can't get that info from login.

You'll need to make a request after login to Google People API to get the desired info. See the example in their documentation: https://developers.google.com/people/v1/read-people